# Что означает первая звездочка в выражении @PointCut("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.*.*(..))")

Tags: java, spring

```
@PointCut("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.*.*(..))")
```

Comment: Смотря с какой стороны читать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это означает, что метод может возвращать любое значение (в т.ч. и void) и иметь любую область видимости.